# Can I call singleton method from a layout XML file as the value of an argument in an `<action>`

Tags: php, xml, magento

As the title says. Can I call singleton method from a layout XML file as the value of an argument in an `<action>`?

For example, can I express the PHP code below as XML in Magento's layout files?

**PHP**

```
$this->addColumn('status', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
    'index' => 'status',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'width' => '70px',
    'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
));
```

**Layout XML**

```
<action method="addColumn">
    <columnId>status</columnId>
    <column translate="header">
        <header>Status</header>
        <index>status</index>
        <type>options</type>
        <width>70px</width>
        <options>What should I put here?</options>
    </column>
</action>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Layout XML actions parameters can be used to pass text, an array structure, *or the return value of a helper* (**grin**). To that last bit, you can create a helper method which does what you want:

```
Some_Module_Helper_Class extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getSalesOrderConfigOptions()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses();
    }
}
```

And in your Layout XML:

```
<action method="addColumn">
    <columnId>status</columnId>
    <column translate="header">
        <header>Status</header>
        <index>status</index>
        <type>options</type>
        <width>70px</width>
        <!-- read as Mage::helper('some_module/class')->getSalesOrderConfig() -->
        <options helper="some_module/class/getSalesOrderConfig" />
        <!-- the return value of the method will be passed as the parameter in this position -->
    </column>
</action>
```

HTH

Comment: @benmarks hi i want to add it in `code`<action method="addColumnAfter"><columnId>status1</columnId>        <arguments module="order" translate="header">                   <header>status</header><index>status</index>                  <filter_index>main_table.status</filter_index>                    <width>70px</width><type>option</type><options helper="module_adminhtml/data/getSalesOrderConfig" />               </arguments><after>grand_total</after></action> `code` in magento admin sales order grid and it is working fine but that drop down is missing, any suggestion will be greate